# Spring call a factory to autowire

Tags: java, spring, factory, autowired

Is there any way to have spring call a factory with a runtime parameter of the type of the parent class of a variable it is trying to autowire?

For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
interface IConfig {
}

interface IConfigProvider {

    IConfig getConfig(Class<?> type)
}

class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private IConfig _config;
}
```

Is there anyway to have spring, when autowiring `MyClass._config` to essentially call `IConfigProvider.getConfig(MyClass.class)` (well the concrete version that is in the context) at runtime to wire the variable?

I know I could autowire the factory and call it myself, I could even "hide" it in a base class but I am trying to avoid this.

NOTE: I am very new to Spring so if I am asking something really stupid/not using the right terminology, I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a `FactoryBean` for that. Something like this should do the trick.

```
class IConfigFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<IConfig> {

    @Autowired
    private IConfigProvider configProvider;

    private IConfig config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        config = configProvider.getConfig(...);
    }


    @Override
    public IConfig getObject() throws Exception {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the argument would be. Note that if you have several instances of `IConfig` you will need to qualify them as Spring won't be able to know which one it has to inject based on a simple `@Autowired` annotation. Check the javadoc of `@Qualifier` for more information.